# gdal2tiles and QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, tiles, tile-map-service, gdal2tiles

I have made a tile pyramid of a number of Dutch topographical maps using `gdal2tiles`. This gives apart from the tiles `openlayers.html` and `tilemapresource.xml`. The openlayers shows perfectly and correctly aligned with respect with the osm layer in a browser.

However, I would like to view them as a layer in QGIS. I have tried various things but to no avail. The nearest thing to something was using the tip in [display tiles with no plugin inside QGIS](http://www.3liz.com/blog/rldhont/index.php?post/2012/07/17/OpenStreetMap-Tiles-in-QGIS). The example xml in web page works but when changing the server into `file:///pdok/top25tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png` I get an inconsistently colored screen. (I changed the projection to EPSG:3785 both in `gdal2tiles.py` and in the xml)

The gdal2tiles line is e.g.:

```
gdal2tiles3785.py -z 15 /pdok/TOP25raster_GEOTIFF/32-top25raster-2013.tif /pdok/top25tiles
```

QGIS is 2.4.0,
GDAL is 1.11.2,
Ubunto is 15.04

Comment: for pyramids in QGIS, I would suggest to use gdaladdo. Tiles are primarily used for servers. note that you can create internally tiled tif with -co TILED=YES (gdal_translate)

Answer (score 1):

I display may self-tiled Dutch cadastral maps in QGIS with the TileLayers Plugin.

In the configuration file, you have to use tabs as delimiters:

```
Topo    Topo    file:///d:/Tiles/Topo/{z}/{x}/{y}.png   1   0   16  -180    -85.0   180.0   85.0
```

If you get strange-coloured tiles, you have to expand from paletted coloured source files to RGBA vrt files before starting the tiling:

```
for %%N in (D:\Karten\gdal\gdal2tiles\NL25\*.tif) DO gdal_translate -of vrt -expand rgba %%N D:\Karten\gdal\gdal2tiles\NL25\%%~nN.vrt
gdalbuildvrt -allow_projection_difference index25.vrt NL25\*.vrt
gdal2tiles --s_srs EPSG:28992 --zoom 15-16 index25.vrt tiles
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to AndreJ's suggestion, another way would be putting the tiles into a mbtiles archive and loading that as layer.

Answer (score 0):

The TileLayers Plugin option I had already tried but results in "Failed to download all tiles". However, I added mb-util to my toolkit and that solved the problem. I had already worked with RasterLite (SpatiaLite) and that worked fine but rasterlite_load did not work on geotiffed historical maps (Bonnebladen) for some reason but this is perfect and fast.