# Displaying tiles build with gdal2tiles in QGIS 2.14

Tags: wms, qgis-2.14, gdal2tiles

I'm trying to create a WMTS service showing an orthophotography.
I've build the tiles with gdal2tiles (https://gdal.gloobe.org/gdal/gdal2tiles.html) and it seems to be ok as i can see the tile in the viewer (leaflet.html) automatically generate by

```
gdal2tiles -s EPSG:2154 -z 16-21 Z:/01_A43/04_RASTER/ORTHO/952500-6500500
.tif C:/ORTHO_TILES
```

The result of such command is a repository (ORTHO_TILES) containing sub-directories (Zoom Level, 16 --> 21) containing sub--directories (referred to X in the world grid), containing tiles which have the name of the Y reference in the world grid.

example : C:/ORTHO_TILES/18/135615/168420.png

looks like this

[image: example]

then i try to visualise this in QGIS with an .xml file. I wrote it as it's specified in http://www.gdal.org/frmt_wms.html

```
 <GDAL_WMS>
  <Service name="TMS">
    <ServerUrl>file://C:/ORTHO_TILES/${z}/${x}/${y}.png</ServerUrl>
  </Service>
  <DataWindow>
   <UpperLeftX>-20037508.34</UpperLeftX>
   <UpperLeftY>20037508.34</UpperLeftY>
   <LowerRightX>20037508.34</LowerRightX>
   <LowerRightY>-20037508.34</LowerRightY>
   <TileLevel>21</TileLevel>
   <TileCountX>1</TileCountX>
   <TileCountY>1</TileCountY>
   <YOrigin>top</YOrigin>
  </DataWindow>
  <Projection>EPSG:3857</Projection>
  <BlockSizeX>256</BlockSizeX>
  <BlockSizeY>256</BlockSizeY>
  <BandsCount>4</BandsCount> 
  <Cache />
</GDAL_WMS>
```

The layer is load in QGIS but nothing appears in the canvas...

In the past, i'va done similary tricks using QTiles to create the TMS repositories and it worked well. I don't understand why with gdal2tiles it's different.

As QGIS doesn't push any error message and a I can zoom on the extent of the layer, it seems that QGIS recognize the xml as a raster without issues.

i have already read this question but there is no answer that worked for me here

[gdal2tiles and qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162746/gdal2tiles-and-qgis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to myself after a few digging in TMS standard.
The YOrigin of this protocol is *bottom* and not *top*...

so the following actually works:

```
<GDAL_WMS>
  <Service name="TMS">
    <ServerUrl>file://ORTHO_TILES/${z}/${x}/${y}.png</ServerUrl>
  </Service>
  <DataWindow>
    <UpperLeftX>-20037508.34</UpperLeftX>
    <UpperLeftY>20037508.34</UpperLeftY>
    <LowerRightX>20037508.34</LowerRightX>
    <LowerRightY>-20037508.34</LowerRightY>
    <TileLevel>21</TileLevel>
    <TileCountX>1</TileCountX>
    <TileCountY>1</TileCountY>
    <YOrigin>bottom</YOrigin>
  </DataWindow>
  <Projection>EPSG:3857</Projection>
  <BlockSizeX>256</BlockSizeX>
  <BlockSizeY>256</BlockSizeY>
  <BandsCount>4</BandsCount> 
  <Cache />
```

Comment: Good that you solved the issue but I wonder why do you want to look local orthophotos with QGIS through TMS.

Comment: For now it's just to test the different software, but at the end the goal is to put all this on a server and give an access to this tiles with QGIS Server and Lizmap. Using WMTS is necessary as the original files are in a tif format and represents 12.4Gb of data (pixels are 10cm by 10cm)

Comment: Makes sense now.